# How to copy a directory from parent to child module with Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, integration-testing, liquibase

I have a spring boot project, built by maven. I have to use a directory included in the parent project for integration testing in the child project. (Liquibase changelog files.)

What is the best practice to copy it under the child module's testing resources?

```
parent
├── my_directory
|
└── child
    └──src
       ├── main
       └── test
           └── resources
```

So I would like to copy my_directory under child/src/main/test/resources which I use in integration testing. Do you have any idea which is the best practice to do it from the child's pom.xml?

Comment: Its is not common situation in general - I believe that you should not use resources from a parent module in a nested module. The direction of the dependency should be from parent to child, not backward. You should fix this issue and problem is gone.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is a useful reflection. The other solution I have found is to put the dependency in a separate module then it will resolve the dependency direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to not use resources from a parent module in a nested module. The dependency should be from parent to child, not child to parent. You can also put the dependency in a separate module to avoid the dependency direction issue altogether.

Reference:

- Comments from @gleb yan and @five above
- [Liquibase Documentation: Tools & Integrations: Maven](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/home.html)